# How can I have only an icon (and not an animation) in a Bottom Navigation View

Tags: java, android, android-animation, bottomnavigationview

Shifting mode closed. When the icon is pressed, icon rises upward. I don't want this to happen. I just want to change the color when the icon is pressed. I want icons in the middle.

This class was implemented:

```
public class BottomNavigationViewHelper {

@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
    try {
        Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
        shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
        shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
        shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
            AppCompatImageView icon = (AppCompatImageView) item.getChildAt(0);
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) icon.getLayoutParams();
            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
    }
}
}
```

in the implemented class:

```
BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigation);
```

layout XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:elevation="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
        app:itemBackground="@color/Gray"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

menu --> bottom_navigation_main xml example:

```
<item   android:id="@+id/star"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_star"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Comment: u want to a false a sifting mode right ?

Comment: shifting mode already false. The icon move up when the icons are pressed. I don't want this to happen.

Comment: i'ts a inbuilt so u can't change but if u want to change color and assign the name of button at bottom

Comment: this is possible without bottom navigation view if u need example how then i'll give u

Comment: You can send mail: yseear24@gmail.com

Thanks.

Comment: I would also do it using linear layout but would it lose performance?

Comment: ya sure bro :) :)

Comment: also i'm using Linerlayout with image and it's work awesome change image, change color all think work fine

Comment: 4 linear layouts. layout_weight : 0.25 and in it imageview. icons will be changed programmatically ?

Comment: yes image icon change programmatically